# Quick way to make connections in IB Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way to connect multiple `UIButtons` to a single property in Xcode in one go, instead of ctrl-dragging one by one to the same property?

many thanks

Comment: did u look into iboutlet collection?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to connect multiple uibuttons to iboutlet collection.

Comment: I'm afraid no one had ever tried this way. I think xcode should enable the multi dragging to outlets just like it do for constraints

Comment: At least in pioneering in something then. lol.... I may talk to the guys at Tech Talk to see if they have an idea...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to connect multiple UIButtons to a single property in
>   Xcode in one go

**No**. 
You need to do it manually one by one.

But, if you are asking to connect **multiple `UIButtons` to a single method**.
Then, **Yes** you can do it.

Create a button and link it to an action. Now do <kbd>option</kbd> + drag, new button will get created with same action method linked to it.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping I could. (I know that when you copy a uibutton it keeps its action, but not what I am looking for).